# Displaying an element in print style does not appear in Chrome Print Preview

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a contact form which I only want to appear in the print version on my web page. I am using Twig, and Contact Form 7.

```
<div class='print-only'>{{ content.accept_form }}</div>
```

And in css:

```
.print-only {
   display: none;
}
```

The print style I have is:

```
@media print {
   transition: none !important;

    div, p, ul {
        page-break-before: avoid;
    }

   .print-only {
       display: block !important;
   }
}
```

While looking at the page with print emulated using Chrome Dev Tools, it appears fine, but, when I open the print dialog to actually print, it is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: It appears fine for me. Should you replace {{ content.accept_form }} with hard coded string, are you able to see? It could be the binding itself not returning anything.

Comment: Good spot - any added strings to that div are showing, but there are other forms in this page that display just fine when printed, as well as this one if I remove the display: none from the main stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was due to some animations on the element causing it to not show. I removed the animations and it worked fine!